# Evaluate variable assignment in AST

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an interpreter for a simple language that only supports arithmetic operations and variable assignments (via `x: ...`). The parser works fine but I'm having conceptual difficulties with evaluating the AST. Here is my grammar:

```
module Grammar where

import Data.Text (Text)

data Stmt = Sequence [Stmt]
          | ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
          | AssignmentExpr AssignmentExpr
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data ArithmeticExpr = Constant Integer
                    | Variable Text
                    | Negation ArithmeticExpr
                    | Sum ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Subtraction ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Product ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Division ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Exponentiation ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data AssignmentExpr = Assignment Text ArithmeticExpr
                    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

And my evaluation code looks like this:

```
module Eval where

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy (State, modify, get)

import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Void (Void)

import Grammar

type Eval = State [(Text, Integer)]

eval :: Stmt -> Eval Void
eval (Sequence stmts)      = undefined -- TODO
eval (ArithmeticExpr expr) = undefined -- TODO
eval (AssignmentExpr expr) = undefined -- TODO

evalArithmeticExpr :: ArithmeticExpr -> Eval Integer
evalArithmeticExpr expr = case expr of
  Constant n -> return n
  Variable v -> do
    env <- get
    case lookup v env of
      Just n -> return n
      Nothing -> error $ "variable '" ++ show v ++ "' not defined"
  Negation e           -> negate <$> evalArithmeticExpr e
  Sum e1 e2            -> (+) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Subtraction e1 e2    -> (-) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Product e1 e2        -> (*) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Division e1 e2       -> div <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Exponentiation e1 e2 -> (^) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2

evalAssignmentExpr :: AssignmentExpr -> Eval ()
evalAssignmentExpr (Assignment var expr) = undefined -- TODO
```

And here I don't know how to implement `evalAssignmentExpr` such that the variable map (realized via `State`) is updated accordingly. I know I'm supposed to use `modify` but I don't quite get how since I don't actually have a value to assign to `var` at this point, only another expression.

Comment: You can use `value <- evalArithmeticExpr expr` so that you have the value to assign to `var`, using `modify` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the way you want to implement `evalAssignmentExpr` is by evaluating the expression in the current state to get a value, and then modifying the state to reflect the new variable assignment using that value.  It would look like:

```
evalAssignmentExpr :: AssignmentExpr -> Eval ()
evalAssignmentExpr (Assignment var expr) = do
  val <- evalArithmeticExpr expr
  modify ((var, val):)
```

Some **spoilers** follow...

Separately, you'll find that you want:

```
eval :: Stmt -> Eval ()
```

with `()` instead of `Void`.  Also, the `ArithmeticExpr` constructor for `Stmt` and the associated case:

```
eval (ArithmeticExpr expr) = evalArithmeticExpr expr
```

don't really make sense.  Evaluation of a statement can't return anything, so an arithmetic expression as a statement doesn't do anything.  (Since expressions don't have side effects in your language, all you can do with an arithmetic expression statement is evaluate it and throw away the result.)

To evaluate a list of statements, you'll want to do a monadic map to evaluate the statements in sequence:

```
eval (Sequence stmts) = mapM_ eval stmts
```

A runnable version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy
import Data.Text
import Data.Void

data Stmt = Sequence [Stmt]
          | AssignmentExpr AssignmentExpr
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data ArithmeticExpr = Constant Integer
                    | Variable Text
                    | Negation ArithmeticExpr
                    | Sum ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Subtraction ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Product ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Division ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    | Exponentiation ArithmeticExpr ArithmeticExpr
                    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data AssignmentExpr = Assignment Text ArithmeticExpr
                    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type Eval = State [(Text, Integer)]

eval :: Stmt -> Eval ()
eval (Sequence stmts)      = mapM_ eval stmts
eval (AssignmentExpr expr) = evalAssignmentExpr expr

evalArithmeticExpr :: ArithmeticExpr -> Eval Integer
evalArithmeticExpr expr = case expr of
  Constant n -> return n
  Variable v -> do
    env <- get
    case lookup v env of
      Just n -> return n
      Nothing -> error $ "variable '" ++ show v ++ "' not defined"
  Negation e           -> negate <$> evalArithmeticExpr e
  Sum e1 e2            -> (+) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Subtraction e1 e2    -> (-) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Product e1 e2        -> (*) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Division e1 e2       -> div <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2
  Exponentiation e1 e2 -> (^) <$> evalArithmeticExpr e1 <*> evalArithmeticExpr e2

evalAssignmentExpr :: AssignmentExpr -> Eval ()
evalAssignmentExpr (Assignment var expr) = do
  val <- evalArithmeticExpr expr
  modify ((var, val):)

main = do
  let pgm = Sequence [ AssignmentExpr (Assignment "x" (Constant 5))
                     , AssignmentExpr (Assignment "y" (Product (Variable "x") (Variable "x")))
                     ]
  print $ runState (eval pgm) []
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems like a great answer (as far as I can tell with my horrible Haskell knowledge). I haven't really given whole `eval` function any though so far because I was stuck with `evalAssignmentExpr` so that's good additional info.

Comment: The evaluation of arithmetic expressions does sort of have a side effect (namely, exceptions when a name is referenced but not yet assigned). So from a "studying PL design" perspective it can make sense to have an embedding of expressions into statements -- and then perhaps later have a static checker that tosses out expressions with no exceptions and/or minimizes exceptional expressions. Designing such a check (and proving that it preserves semantics) are very normal activities when designing more realistic languages.

Comment: @Peter, my best guess is that someone felt my answer to your precise question lacked detail, as much of the answer was "answering" questions you didn't ask.  My second best guess is that I answered a "controversial" question the other day, and maybe someone threw a tantrum (though I'd have expected more downvotes, and this is only one I've seen).